# Using socket.io to replace polling mechanism against Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I have a application that I am working on that uses Mongodb and Nodejs. There is another external web services which collects data and updates Mongodb. I would like to have a way to publish those changes automatically in web page without doing actual polling. Currently, I am using polling mechanism within socket.io to push the changes to UI. Is it possible to refresh UI with auto publishing the changes from Mongodb using socket.io?

Answer (score 2):

So there is no control over the web service, it's an external application that uploads data to mongo.

MongoDB provides a special type of polling for new data, which does not cover the case where existing data is modified.

This optimized polling on new data can be made by combining MongoDB’s capped collections and tailable cursors features. Here is a [blog post of how to do it](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/29495793738/pub-sub-with-mongodb), and a [code example](https://gist.github.com/scttnlsn/3210919).

So the way to implement what you mention is via polling, and there is this optimization available for the case of new data only.

**If there was access to the uploading web service:**

For a solution without polling using server socket.io push, you would need to make the upload web service run in the same node process, and from the callback that saves in Mongo call `io.sockets.emit('yourChannel', newData);`, to broadcast the new data to all browser clients.

Comment: I think you didn't get the question. May be I didn't explain it right. What you just described as how we are using socket.io, just exact process to update UI. However, our problem is that - some external application (not web necessarily) updates database (mongodb). Socket.IO updates UI by doing poll every 10 seconds on the database to see if data has changed and pushes the change to the clients. The question really is - is polling necessary every 10 seconds to mongodb or is there a smarter way to auto notify changes in mongodb?

Comment: OK, I have fixed the answer according to that

Comment: I was also inclining towards using cap collection of Mongodb and tailable cursors. But interestingly, there is one more thing that caught my attention - Monitoring Oplogs attaching tailable cursor. This way, we can achieve what we want for inserts, updates and deletes. If I am successful in that pursuit, well let that known here. Thanks for your help.